# Grails Spring Security Plugin Password issue

Tags: spring, security, grails, migration, spring-security

I have successfully migrated to Spring Security plugin from acegi plugin.  Creating a new user works fine. I can login.

But in the database, I have lot of users created using acegi's `authenticateService.encodePassword`. So I can't login using those old username and password. I guess its the MD5 or SHA1 encoding algorithm issue.

Just wanted to know, how to make it to work without resetting password. I tried setting    `grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm="MD5"`, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

package auth

```
import java.util.Set;
import auth.Role

/**
 * User domain class.
 */
class User  implements Serializable {
    static transients = ['pass','getAuthorities']
    static hasMany = [authorities: Role]
    static belongsTo = Role

    transient springSecurityService

    static mapping = {
        table 'users' // USER not a valid table name in oracle
    }

    /** Username */
    String username
    /** User Real Name*/
    String userRealName
    /** MD5 Password */
    String passwd

    String password

    /** enabled */
    boolean enabled

    String email
    boolean emailShow

    /** description */
    String description = ''

    /** plain password to create a MD5 password */
    String pass = '[secret]'

    boolean accountExpired 
    boolean accountLocked 
    boolean passwordExpired  

    String toString() {
        return userRealName
    }

    static constraints = {
        username(blank: false, unique: true)
        userRealName(blank: false)
        passwd(blank: false)
        password(blank: false)
        enabled()
        description(nullable:true)
    }

    /*Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        Role.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }*/

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password,null)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm='SHA-512'
```

in

```
config.groovy
```

Comment: Nope. Same error."Authentication failed: password does not match stored value." Anything else I am missing or some clue ?

Comment: Does acegi uses md5Hex ? If so how to add it in config ?

Comment: I figured it out.It was SHA1 used before. Thanx everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to declaring the correct algorithm, you have to actually call the password encoder. In my `User` class I do it like this:

```
class User {

    def springSecurityService
    static transients = ['springSecurityService', 'passwordConfirm']

    String password
    String passwordConfirm

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {            
            password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, null)
            passwordConfirm = springSecurityService.encodePassword(passwordConfirm, null)
    }
}
```